# "Inaccessible boot device" when booting a RamDisk "Windows server 2016 standard VHD"

Tags: windows, vhd, ramdisk, grub4dos

I need to boot a "Windows Server 2016 Standard VHD" from RamDisk.
Few seconds after booting from RamDisk, the system display the message "Inaccessible boot device".

Below is the `grub4dos menu.lst` used:

```
...
find --set-root /Win2016Audio.vhd
map --mem /Win2016Audio.vhd (hd0)
map --hook
root (hd0,0)
chainloader /bootmgr
boot
...
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is the vhd partition primary and active ?
Is the vhd standard or dynamic ?
Are the boot files enumerated ?

Comment: Problem is now solved. Vhd is primary and active and standard. The problem was in the .reg file I use for firadisk driver. The .reg that I find on the web contains different (unsimilar) characters for the double quotes, so this put the mess in registry.

Answer (score 1):

> **The problem** was in the `.reg` file I use for firadisk driver.
>
> - Apparently the `.reg` that I used contains different/dissimilar characters for double quotes, so this caused trouble with the registry
>     import of those characters.
>
> [kali mera](https://superuser.com/users/978076/kali-mera)